# Restricting access when using URL - Drupal

Tags: drupal, urlaccess

I have created several pages in my drupal website and set permissions to each of the page depending upon the roles I have.
The problem is if I know the URL, I can access that page even though I am not a registered and authorized user.

This will be a problem if some random person/hacker plays around with the URLs and comes across a page that is supposed to be viewed by an authorized user.

I am new to Drupal and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly set the permissions it will restrict access based on roles regardless if they know the URL.  Are you sure that when you are testing it you are actually signed into or using a role that doesn't have access to that page?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal lets you set permissions for who can Create, Edit and Delete content types. You need a contributed module for setting who can 'View' permissions of individual pages/nodes.

Download Content Access from https://drupal.org/project/content_acces. After you install it and configure the default values for the content type, you will need to click the content access tab after you create the page.

'Taxonomy Access Control Lite' is very light and more user-friendly; permissions are set within the edit view (normal fields), however, it takes some effort to understand how it works and to set it up.

See a comprehensive list of node access modules at https://drupal.org/node/270000

Tip: Don't use more than one module for node access permissions.